# WP Page Navi. 404 error when using posts per page parameter

Tags: pagination, 404-error, plugin-wp-pagenavi

I'm trying to fix an error with pagination of WP page Navi plugin. After I've added posts_per_page parameter to the query I'm getting 404 error when clicking on link page3,4 etc (there are 10 records totally) and after page 8 (where there around 60 records totally). Without this parameter it works fine but I want to display various number of posts under categories.

Here is the code of one of the pages I'm trying to fix:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts($query_string .'&posts_per_page=5&paged=' . $paged);
?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
<?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')){ wp_pagenavi(); } ?>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Never use query_posts, it will cause problems like breaking pagination. Use WP_Query or get_posts instead.

Comment: Actually, I've tried to use WP_Query instead of query_posts but problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've found an answer. Not sure if it's specific in my case or it's a general WP issue but default value for posts per page set up in WP admin (General > Reading > Maximum number of posts per page) should be less than value for posts_per_page parameter for custom query. In my case, I've changed in WP options value to 3 and for other page changed this to 5 and all working fine now!

Comment: This is happening because you are running a custom query when you should **not**. This is in all probability on your home page or some kind of archive page like category.php.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this related issue:
[WP-PageNavi gives me a 404 when using WP Query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31524/wp-pagenavi-gives-me-a-404-when-using-wp-query)

Some users mentioning that the page name cannot be the same as the post type you are querying, and others that it may be a conflict with another plugin you are running.